# update message to status bar

Tags: c++, mfc

"update message to status bar for multi documents in visual studio"
I create a Visual Studio (MFC) multi-documents with CEditView.
Could you provide examples for write messages to status bar?

[image]

Comment: See [status bars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/status-bars), or [CStatusBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cstatusbar-class) and [CMFCStatusBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcstatusbar-class) for the respective MFC wrappers.

Comment: Your menus must contain strings, in a certain formatted way, and they will be automatically displayed there, as well as hints in their associated toolbar buttons. They are stored in the string-table. Check the wizard-generated menus and you will easily figure it out.